# Artifacts in plotting shapefiles with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, shapefile

In attempting to plot U.S. Counties from the Census Bureau's 2013 shapefile, the resulting plot has holes/weird fills, especially around counties with discontinuous regions.  I think it has something to do with the order of the the points that are plotted, but am not sure how it can be fixed.  For example, a plot of Florida, particularly around the Keys produces:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)

download.file('http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2013/cb_2013_us_county_500k.zip',
'county.zip')
unzip('county.zip')

uscounties <- readOGR(.,'cb_2013_us_county_500k' )
uscounties@data$id <- rownames(uscounties@data)
countypoints <- fortify(uscounties, region='id')
countydf <- join(countypoints, uscounties@data, by='id')

ggplot(countydf[countydf$STATEFP=='12' ,])+
  aes(long, lat, group=COUNTYNS, fill=STATEFP)+
  geom_polygon()+
  geom_path(color="black")+
  coord_equal()
```

Here is the resulting plot :
[image]
Florida is just an example.  Most other states will display similar errors in plotting as well.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get an error in `readOGR(.,'cb_2013_us_county_500k' )` that `Error in nchar(dsn) : object '.' not found`.  Can you please make your code reproducible?

Comment: Also, in which package is the function `join()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you setting `group=COUNTYNS`?? Use `group=id`.

```
ggplot(countydf[countydf$STATEFP=='12' ,])+
  aes(long, lat, group=group, fill=STATEFP)+
  geom_polygon()+geom_path(color="black")+coord_equal()
```

[image]

You need to take more care when posting a question, so as not to waste peoples' time.. `join(...)` is in package `plyr` not `dplyr`, and

```
readOGR(.,"...")
```

doesn't work, you need

```
readOGR(dsn=".",layer="...")
```

Comment: In similar problem your solution works for me, but only if I use `group=group` as you write in the block of code. The `group=id` version still generates artifacts.